# LPTHW ex50. : Error while using the template code

Tags: python, html, templates

I am on [this](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex50.html) exercise.
I am having trouble understanding the template code that is given.
When I copy-pasted the code and made a template as desired just so that I could run it
, I got the error `No template named index`

```
$def with (greeting)

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gothons Of Planet Percal #25</title>
    </head>
<body>

$if greeting:
    I just wanted to say <em style="color: green; font-size: 2em;">$greeting</em>.
$else:
    <em>Hello</em>, world!

</body>
</html>
```

Why is the $ sign used ? I am on windows so am I supposed write the same code?

Also where I am supposed to store the `templates/index.html` file ?

In the first line have they actually defined a function `def with (greeting)`?

Is the whole code semantically correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing HTML and PHP

PHP is declared like this

```
<?php

PHP code in here.

?>
```

The $ is used to define variables. Such as :

```
$tablelegs = 4;

if($tablelegs = 4)
{
echo "Is a table with 4 legs";
}
else
echo "Is not a table";
```

Comment: Actually I dont know php at all.How would I confuse it with HTML.
Can you help me with the " no template named index error"